# Resource of the recommended and modern EcmaScript commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2017

I am in the process of learning JS/ES, and to see if I have understood OOP correctly, would I for each of OOP code snippets in my text book, like to write the same as non OOP, to see if I have understood the OOP code example correctly. That way I can do an A/B comparison.

Here is a simple example:

```
var clock = {
  start() {
    setInterval(() => console.log(Date()), 1000) 
  }
}
clock.start()
```

In pseudo I would do

```
while (1) {
  print Date()
  sleep 1000
}
```

**Question**

The easiest would be to Google for `while` loop and something about `sleep` together with JavaScript, but then would end up with the JS way of doing it rather than a modern EcmaScript way.

Is there a resource (online book or documentation) that lists the preferred EcmaScript way commands?

The above example is super simple, but the book have very complicated examples later on, so I would like to have a way to rewrite those.

Comment: These snippets have nothing to do with each other, and are not related to OOP vs non-OOP.

Comment: There is no `sleep` in Javascript.  Javascript in the browser or node.js is an event driven environment.  Also, there is no such thing as a JS way and an ECMAScript way.  ECMAScript is what the standards organization describes.  Implementations of that standards are often referred to by their common name Javascript.  They aren't two different languages or way of doing things. There are different versions of the standards, ES3, ES4, ES5, ES6, then it switches to years ES2019 and so on.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I mean with JS way and ES way are e.g. in JS have anonymous functions and ES introduced arrow functions as a more modern version. So I am looking for a resource that lists the preferred way to code. E.g. I would expect there are multipel ways to do a `while` loop. Yes, `sleep` is pseudo, so here I would have to do some more coding.

Comment: JS and ES are not different things.  Arrow functions were introduced in a specific version of the ES specification.  We have lots of different JS implementations of that specification.